# slim framework - using arrays and variables

Tags: php, arrays, slim

I have an array in my index.php file;

```
$teamnames = array('bristol_city', 'bristol_thunder', 'bristol_uni', 'exeter_city', 'exeter_uni', 'gloucester', 'horfield', 'taunton');
```

Then I have a "controller" and I want to pass that array in to the `add-report.php` view;

```
$app->get('/report/add', function () use($app) {
    $app->render('add-report.php', array());
});
```

I have tried adding `$teamnames` to `array()` and then trying to do a print_r on the view but all I get is an error;

```
Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Undefined variable: teamnames
File: /vagrant/ref-feedback/index.php
Line: 18
```

I am brand new to Slim and cannot find any documentation on this at all....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$app->get('/report/add', function () use($app) {
    $teamnames = array('bristol_city', 'bristol_thunder', '...');
    $app->render('add-report.php', array('teamnames' => $teamnames));
});
```

The array will be extracted into the view, so now you may use `print_r($teamnames)` in the view.

Comment: Additionally, if `$teamnames` is defined outside of your current routes, you could curry `$teamnames` to the routes in exactly the same way you're currently currying `$app`.  Your route definition(s) would become `$app->get('/route/pattern', function () use ($app, $teamnames) { ... });`.